# Will the device context of a child window have the same text metrics and text extents as its parents (up to GA_ROOT) with the same HFONT?

Tags: winapi

Right now I have code to manually compute the dialog base units for a non-dialog; these calculations involve getting a window's HDC and [extracting the text metrics for that HDC as well as the text extents for the base X unit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/125681). This is used by parent controls that arrange and lay out children in a line, grid, etc.; the DLUs are used to conform to the sizing specifications provided by Microsoft in their (old) UI guidelines (not sure what the new ones say, if anything).

However, my code right now is run on every parent window for every child window in the window tree. Not only is this inefficient, but it's also inconsistent: do I calculate the base units for the child or its parent when computing the size the child wants to be? (All children have the same font as the parent.)

I could optimize this by assuming that if I select the same font into the HDC of a parent and the HDC of a child, the text extents and metrics will be identical. If this is true, then I can simply get these base units once, for the toplevel window that hosts all these children controls (`GetAncestor(GA_ROOT)`), and then use them through the entire control layout process. So **is this true**?

If that is true, under what conditions will the values be likely to change, DPI/monitor change only? Or something else?

And if that is not true, whose (parent's or child's) window dialog base units do I get for what (position and size)?

(Note: I'm talking about parents and children, not owners and owned windows.)

Thanks.

Comment: Why are your child windows concerned with dialog units? With regular dialogs they're only used in the dialog template. The child windows (controls) never care about them and normally nothing does after the dialog window is created.

Comment: Because the metrics I use to determine the controls's ideal sizes are in DLUs (they're straight from Microsoft).

Comment: The ideal size returned by the various XXX_GETIDEALSIZE messages for certain standard controls is in pixels not DLUs. If you mean the *typical* sizes given Microsoft's old UI guidelines (eg. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997619.aspx) then Microsoft's controls don't care about them either. Microsoft's controls display themselves with the size and position, given in pixels, that they're told to use. They don't know anything about DLUs and they don't need to know. So why do your controls care about them?

Comment: My controls don't. My code to position and size those standard controls into boxes and grids according to the typical sizes given by Microsoft's old UI guidelines do. Did Microsoft change things in their new UI guidelines that I don't know about? Or do those only cover UWP apps? And unfortunately too few controls provide `GETIDEALSIZE` messages for me to use :/

Comment: So why you have child windows that aren't controls that do care about DLUs? This is something regular dialogs don't have, as the only child windows are controls and they don't care about DLUs. You also appear to be misusing the old UI guidelines. They were meant to be used intelligently by a human when creating dialog templates, usually through some sort of dialog editor. The typical values are given for the sake of consistency, and so were only meant to be used were consistency was both desirable and practical. They aren't "ideal" and weren't meant to be used in programs.

Comment: Because those are still best practices, unless you are telling me that they are not best practicies and should be ignored? What would you suggest instead? (I hope I'm not coming off as unwilling to be helped; I'm actually curious in what your point of view on the mater is.) For what it's worth, a few of those have also told me important sizing metrics; for example, the old MMC guidelines state that the left edge of a checkbox/radiobutton is always 12 dlu away from the left edge of its text, so I can figure out what the preferred width of the label is: 12 dlu in pixels+width of text in pixels.

Comment: Why do you have child windows that aren't controls that do care about DLUs? You can't justify that with "best practices", since that practice isn't followed by regular dialogs and controls.

Comment: What practice is followed by regular dialogs and controls that is "best practice" then? These non-standard controls arrange and lay out other controls in a structured way, such as linearly or in a grid; I'm not using a visual resource editor for this. (I edited the question to make this more clear.) Or do you mean only dialogs have standard controls to begin with?

Comment: You said before that your controls don't care about DLUs but now you're apparently saying you have non-standard controls that do care about DLUs. If these controls exist only to layout other controls than they're unnecessary. If you want to follow the practice set by Windows dialogs, ignoring the fact the that they're meant be designed by humans, then at runtime you can create a "template" with a hierarchical structured layout without creating a hierarchy of child windows. Maybe even create a real dialog template in memory and use it to create a standard dialog.

Comment: Ah, now I see the confusion. When I said control I was always referring to standard controls. I see what you are suggesting now; thanks. The only issue is that I also need to be able to change the layout at runtime (for instance, showing a previously hidden standard control that would require other controls to be resized). Still, I suppose you are right about human design being the best practice... I'm still curious about this since the flattened control structure is not feasible (I have tried it already).

Comment: I hate to ask, but does anyone else know the answer? I'm at the point in this rewrite process where I need to rewrite the resizing logic.