# Do child windows have the same DPI as their parents in a per-monitor-aware application?

Tags: windows, winapi, dpi

***Optional background information***

A while ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756094/will-the-device-context-of-a-child-window-have-the-same-text-metrics-and-text-ex) which specifically talks about text sizes and DLUs, and was made without me realizing what each DPI awareness actually meant. It never went anywhere, however. It's most likely my fault for not writing a clear question by asking about my implementation-specific problem rather than the general problem that comes out of it ("xX Problem"?).

I asked that question because I was writing a dynamic GUI layout engine — one that could handle changes to control presence and visibility — and needed to know which window the base units would be relative to. At the time, I decided that coordinates should be based on the parent and sizes should be based on the child, but now I realize that'll cause problems if the child's DPI is larger than the parent's.

Of course, this type of thing extends beyond just DLU calculation. For instance, a window that draws pictures on both vertical halves will have to worry about the per-monitor DPI changing right down the middle. So allow me to ask the general, unambiguous question.

---

***The actual question***

Today I found these two MSDN articles:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt744321(v=vs.85).aspx

After reading them, I now understand this much about system DPI awarenesses:

- `PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE`

  - when asked for the DPI of something, the system will give the DPI of the primary monitor
  - this value cannot and thus will not change throughout the lifetime of the program
  - is equivalent to calling the older `SetProcessDPIAware()`
- `PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE`

  - like `PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE` except the DPI is fixed at 96
- `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE`

  - the system gives the DPI of whatever monitor a window happens to be on; when that changes, a `WM_DPICHANGED` is sent
  - the page on that message says this can also happen if the monitor DPI changes; I didn't know you could do that now

What I would like to know is:

**In the case of `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE`, is the DPI of all child (NOT owned) windows of a window the same as that of the parent window?**

Note the superlative: the part about the DPI not changing for the life of the program means that the answer is "yes" for the other two awareness values.

Or as another example, let's say I have a 300px-wide window with two controls, both 100px wide, at opposite edges. If I drag that window between two monitors with different DPIs such that one of the controls is on one monitor and the other control is on the other, and then query their DPI (using `GetDC()` and `GetDeviceCaps()`), will they be the same?

If the answer is yes, then I will not need to worry about converting coordinates between parent windows and child windows.

If the answer is no, then the next question would be is `WM_DPICHANGED` sent to child windows, or only to toplevels? Because I would still need a way to know when the DPI of the children changed, so I can at least *try* to rearrange it to look correct (which I have not yet figured out how to do, and which is another question entirely, but which I assume should just be `MulDiv()`).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't write DPI-aware code yet, and I've always wondered how a DPI-aware window handles the case when it spans across multiple monitors of different DPIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the system decides that the majority of the window has crossed over onto the other monitor, the top level window is sent `WM_DPICHANGED` and the entire window is expected to be resized for the new DPI.

In other words, the system does not attempt to have windows with mixed DPI.

Comment: And thus, by extension, all children have the toplevel's DPI. Thanks! (I imagine the people holding windows halfway between monitors would be surprised that half look blurry due to that scaling, but I wouldn't know for sure as I don't have a high-DPI monitor yet :/ )

Comment: You don't need a high DPI monitor to test. You just need two monitors. Bump one of them up as high as you can. For sure it looks silly, but you can test the system.

Comment: Consider also covering the case the OP did not think of, a context menu.

Comment: @Hans I can't say I've though of that myself. If I had to guess I would ingrained that the system never places them across two monitors. But I wonder what happens when you straddle two monitors with your window, and ask for a context menu at a point on the window that sits on the minority DPI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If the context menu is displayed entirely on one monitor, it gets the DPI of that monitor (and not the underlying parent). I guess if you were able to get a context menu to straddle two monitors it would obey the same rules and use the DPI of whichever monitor had more of it.